# Add a hardcoded value in object_construct in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using Snowflake's Object_Construct to create a JSON array with values.

Most of the values in the JSON response are from Table columns but I also need to hardcode some metadata attributes such as language_code to 'en' etc which are not available in table. I tried few options like 'language_code' as 'en' or values('language_code','en') but it is not working.

Sample Code:

```
with address as (
SELECT address_id,
 array_agg(object_construct(
'addressKey',address_key,
'ChangeTime',CHANGE_TMST,
'addressType',ADDRESS_TYPE,
'ADDRESS_LINE_1',ADDRESS_LINE_1,
'ADDRESS_LINE_2',ADDRESS_LINE_2,
'ADDRESS_LINE_3',ADDRESS_LINE_3,
--'languageCode','en',
))
from ADDRESS
group by address_id)
```

Language Code is commented in the sample code. Please suggest.

Comment: Provide more details on the issue, what exactly did you tried and what was the output received vs expected output. Did you tried anything like following - select OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(key1,value_1, 'lang','en') from TABLE_NAME;

Comment: Added sample code that is not working

Comment: Define "not working." Are you getting an error? Different output than you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you're using should work just fine:

```
SELECT address_id,
 array_agg(object_construct(
 'addressKey',address_key,
 ...
 'languageCode','en'
))
from ADDRESS
group by address_id;
```

It's possible that your error is coming from the surrounding query syntax. I notice you're defining an `address` table and also trying to select from a table called `ADDRESS`: Snowflake treats unquoted identifiers as if they are capitalized, so the CTE would be named the same as the table, which might cause issues. You're also including an extra comma at the end of your argument list that will cause syntax errors.

This example executes just fine, though:

```
with ADDRESS as (
  select a.* from (values (1, 'one'),(1, 'one-again'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')) as a(address_id, address_key)
)
SELECT address_id,
 array_agg(object_construct(
'addressKey',address_key,
'languageCode','en'
))
from ADDRESS
group by address_id;
```

Comment: Thanks @StriplingWarrior for your inputs. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

So if we make a tiny table of values to check the object_construct:

```
with data(address_id, address_key,CHANGE_TMST, ADDRESS_TYPE, ADDRESS_LINE_1, ADDRESS_LINE_2, ADDRESS_LINE_3)   as (
    select * from values
    ( 1, 'ak1', '2022-06-24 20:18:12'::timestamp, 'type1', 'line1', 'line2', null ),
    ( 2, 'ak2', '2021-06-24 20:18:12'::timestamp, 'type2', 'line1', 'line2', 'line3' )
)
```

and use you inner object code

```
select object_construct(
    'addressKey',address_key,
    'ChangeTime',CHANGE_TMST,
    'addressType',ADDRESS_TYPE,
    'ADDRESS_LINE_1',ADDRESS_LINE_1,
    'ADDRESS_LINE_2',ADDRESS_LINE_2,
    'ADDRESS_LINE_3',ADDRESS_LINE_3,
    'languageCode','en'
)
from data;
```

| OBJECT_CONSTRUCT( 'ADDRESSKEY',ADDRESS_KEY, 'CHANGETIME',CHANGE_TMST, 'ADDRESSTYPE',ADDRESS_TYPE, 'ADDRESS_LINE_1',ADDRESS_LINE_1, 'ADDRESS_LINE_2',ADDRESS_LINE_2, 'ADDRESS_LINE_3',ADDRESS_LINE_3, 'LANGUAGECODE','EN' ) |
| --- |
| { "ADDRESS_LINE_1": "line1", "ADDRESS_LINE_2": "line2", "ChangeTime": "2022-06-24 20:18:12.000", "addressKey": "ak1", "addressType": "type1", "languageCode": "en" } |
| { "ADDRESS_LINE_1": "line1", "ADDRESS_LINE_2": "line2", "ADDRESS_LINE_3": "line3", "ChangeTime": "2021-06-24 20:18:12.000", "addressKey": "ak2", "addressType": "type2", "languageCode": "en" } |

we get exactly what we would expect.

If we then change those two lines to have the same address id, just so grouping can be shown to work:

```
with data(address_id, address_key,CHANGE_TMST, ADDRESS_TYPE, ADDRESS_LINE_1, ADDRESS_LINE_2, ADDRESS_LINE_3)   as (
    select * from values
    ( 1, 'ak1', '2022-06-24 20:18:12'::timestamp, 'type1', 'line1', 'line2', null ),
    ( 1, 'ak2', '2021-06-24 20:18:12'::timestamp, 'type2', 'line1', 'line2', 'line3' )
)
select 
    address_id,
    array_agg(
object_construct(
    'addressKey',address_key,
    'ChangeTime',CHANGE_TMST,
    'addressType',ADDRESS_TYPE,
    'ADDRESS_LINE_1',ADDRESS_LINE_1,
    'ADDRESS_LINE_2',ADDRESS_LINE_2,
    'ADDRESS_LINE_3',ADDRESS_LINE_3,
    'languageCode','en'
)) as addresses
from data
group by 1;
```

we get:

| ADDRESS_ID | ADDRESSES |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ { "ADDRESS_LINE_1": "line1", "ADDRESS_LINE_2": "line2", "ChangeTime": "2022-06-24 20:18:12.000", "addressKey": "ak1", "addressType": "type1", "languageCode": "en" }, { "ADDRESS_LINE_1": "line1", "ADDRESS_LINE_2": "line2", "ADDRESS_LINE_3": "line3", "ChangeTime": "2021-06-24 20:18:12.000", "addressKey": "ak2", "addressType": "type2", "languageCode": "en" } ] |

So it all appears as I would expect, and working just fine. Can you describe what you are seeing that is not "as you expect" or what error you might be getting?